# how to clean a query string in a URL?

Tags: r, regex, url, stringr

Consider this simple example

`www.stackunderflow.com?q=snack%20over%20flow`

I am interested in parsing the query string of the url. However, as you can see, I have these annoying URL encoding strings (such as `%20`) that I need convert.

How can I do that in R? I would like to obtain a clean string such as `snack over flow`. I know how to get the query part :

```
> str_match('www.stackunderflow.com?q=snack%20over%20flow', regex('\\?q=(.*)'))[,2]
[1] "snack%20over%20flow"
```

but I dont know how to clean the string.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you committed to doing this via regex? Almost certainly r has a url parsing function (or library etc) that can do this and more for you.

Comment: regex is good because portable

Comment: portable to where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find the urltools package usefull here

```
# install.packages("urltools")
library(urltools)
url_decode("snack%20over%20flow")
#[1] "snack over flow"
```

Answer (score 4):

Also the `httr` package:

```
httr::parse_url("www.stackunderflow.com?q=snack%20over%20flow")
```

> ```
> $`scheme`
> NULL
>
> $hostname
> NULL
>
> $port
> NULL
>
> $path
> [1] "www.stackunderflow.com"
>
> $query
> $query$`q`
> [1] "snack over flow"
>
>
> $params
> NULL
>
> $fragment
> NULL
>
> $username
> NULL
>
> $password
> NULL
>
> attr(,"class")
> [1] "url"
> ```

So you can call `parse_url(SOME_URL)$query` to get that string. Under the hood, it's calling `httr::parse_query` to split the query into pieces, and then on each piece it calls `curl::curl_unescape`, which calls the C implementation (from libcurl) to decode such strings.

Answer (score 3):

The `utils` package, which comes with R, has a `URLdecode` function:

```
URLdecode("snack%20over%20flow")
# [1] "snack over flow"
```

It isn't vectorized (can only handle one string at a time), but that's easy to change.

```
URLdecode_vec <- Vectorize(URLdecode)
URLdecode_vec(c("snack%20over%20flow", "snack%20over%20flow"))
# snack%20over%20flow snack%20over%20flow 
#   "snack over flow"   "snack over flow"
```

Answer (score 1):

One with `sub` and `gsub`. Using `sub` extract the part after `"?q="` and with `gsub` remove the `"%"` followed by a number and replace it with empty space.

```
string <- "www.stackunderflow.com?q=snack%20over%20flow"
gsub("%\\d+", " ", sub(".*\\?q=(.*)", "\\1", string))
#[1] "snack over flow"
```

Comment: However, `%27` is not a space, but your code will still replace it with a space.

Comment: Yes, the code will replace anything with `%` followed by number with space. Honestly, I don't know the significance of `%27` though.

Comment: @RonakShah Many punctuation marks are encoded that way. %27 would represent a single-quote, not a space. See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: its an interesting solution but what if I have anothe query parameter in the url? the regex does not work anymore

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ what would be an example of that?

Comment: "www.stackunderflow.com?q=snack%20over%20flow&ronak=123"

Comment: this returns `"snack over flow&ronak=123"` but I am not sure what would be your expected output in this case?

Comment: just "snack over flow'. The `&` in the url shows that another query parameter is coming up

Comment: you could change it to `gsub("%\\d+", " ", sub(".*\\?q=(.*)&.*", "\\1", string))` then.

Comment: yes but there is not always an additional parameter... can we make it not greedy with optional `&` ?